# metric_relabel_configs: What happens if labels become non-unique?

Tags: prometheus

In several articles I find stuff like this on the use of `metric_relabels_config`:

> Note, with label dropping you need to ensure that the final metrics after label drop are still uniquely labeled and not resulting in duplicate time-series with different values.

*[source](https://medium.com/quiq-blog/prometheus-relabeling-tricks-6ae62c56cbda)*

**But what happens if an `action` results in a time-series with a label combination that already exists?**

Use-case: Using the relabeling to move http time-series with return codes like `404` and `403` to `4xx` and so on. Does this work correctly (adding up the values) or will Prometheus enter "undefined state"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time series will clash, and will not all be ingested. This is not something you want.

> Does this work correctly (adding up the values)

For addition you need the data inside Prometheus's TSDB first, as only PromQL is where aggregation would happen.